# After replacing my motherboard I lost the boot option for Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows, hard-drive

I just replaced my motherboard, and now my Windows hard drive (secondary) seems not to be detected. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on my main hard drive and Windows 10 on my 2nd.

Comment: Brand and model of your mobo, at least? Look, Windows use to become not functional after some hardware changes, as mobo and processors, e.g

Comment: Its not a desktop. Its a hp elite book 8470p.

Comment: You can run, from Ubuntu, `sudo update-grub`. That *may* bring the Windows bootloader entry back but it is unlikely to work. As commented before Windows needs reinstalling (or recovered) whenever the base hardware is changed and then re-activated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo update-grub` detected the extra drive.